# Prematurely flowering wallflowers

Tags: flowers

Every year I grow wallflowers (*Erysimum cheiri*) for spring bedding in my garden. This year, as usual, I sowed them in July in order to plant out now in early November. However, unlike in previous years, most of them are now prematurely in flower (it has been fairly mild here recently). Do you think they will flower again at the normal time next spring? I live just north of London, UK. The variety, which I haven't grown before, is "Monarch Fair Lady".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most wallflowers need short day lengths to start their flowering cycle, so they only flower in spring. There are a few varieties that are sold as autumn flowering as well as spring flowering. For those, just remove the dead flowers after the winter weather has ended the autumn flowering season.

I don't think Monarch Fair Lady is actually *sold* as autumn flowering, but maybe it has some traits in common with the autumn flowering varieties. I would just treat it the same way.